# Create docker image from linux server on azure

Tags: linux, azure, docker

I'm new to Docker, but I want to make an "image" for docker of my current server I have running on Azure. Now, I have readed the documentation, but that always tells me that I can make a new image... I want to image my current server to a docker file.

How can I do this? Like let's say, I have a linux server running on Azure with all my configuration settings applied on it. How can I do this? I really need this fast... I can test the created docker image on a computer of someone else, so how can I do this? Or what solution would that be?

Comment: interesting idea...

Comment: Yes, would be really hand if you could have some sort of command to make an image of a current server or if you snapshot a server and can make a docker image from it?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot convert your existing Linux box to a docker image. This is not how docker Works.

You can take a snapshot of your VM and créate another identical vm, not container.

Answer (score 0):

For now, there is no way to make a docker image from an existing server.

If you want to build your self docker image, you should [build](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#tarball-contexts) docker image with **docker file**.

Or download an existing docker image, then do some change to it and [save](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/) it as new image.

Hope this helps.